# A question on the average velocity and acceleration of electrons in a metal conductor and why only the former is zero

Tags: electricity

While studying electricity, I came across the fact that the average velocity of particles when they collide with other particles is zero as it's totally random. By this logic, shouldn't average /drift velocity also be zero. One could argue that the electric field "polarizes" the acceleration in one direction, however, going by this the velocities at the time of collision are also,"polarized"(for the lack of better words). so why isn't that zero, in that case.

For those wanting the book, it's ncert  , class 12, chapter 3, part I. I would attach the link, but ncert;s website usually doesn't work for me.

Comment: This link may help http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/miccur.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. just went through the link, however, this hasn't helped me understand why the average initial velocity(V just after collision) is zero, whereas the acceleration and therefore average velocity isn't. Thanks again!

Comment: "came across the fact that the average velocity of particles when they collide with other particles is zero as it's totally random."  It is a general observation because if the thermal collisions in a lattice did not add up to zero velocity for average, the object would move! due to conservation of momentum. Directional motion as in a conductor is both ways for a closed circuit, otherwise there will be motion of the whole lattice attracted or repulsed by the fields.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you!